# a linear map on a finite-dimensional space is open

Tags: real-analysis

I have some difficulty with this problem.
Let X be a finite-dimensional normed linear space and let Y be normed linear space. Suppose that $T: X\rightarrow Y $ is linear. Prove that T is open.
I know we can prove that T is continuous and X is Banach space. But Y is not complete so I couldn't apply the open mapping theorem. So how to prove T is open? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is not true. The map $Tx = 0$ is not open. You need surjectivity at least.

Comment: You need surjectivity, which automatically implies $Y$ is finite dimensional, hence complete, so the open mapping theorem applies, even if it is overkill.

Comment: Thanks. But Could I apply the open mapping theorem to T(X)? Is T(X) complete?

Comment: @copper.hat `@JonasMeyer The textbook from which the question comes uses the alternative definition of an open map: A mapping $T:X\to Y$ from the topological space $X$ to the topological space $Y$ is said to be _open_ provided the image of each open set in $X$ is open in the topological space $T(X)$ where $T(X)$ has the subspace topology inherited from $Y$.

Comment: @user0 that is the standard, not alternative, definition.

Comment: @copper.hat (I thought that you were using the definition that the image of an open set in $X$ be open in $Y$.) Then I do not understand your counterexample above.  I claim that if $T$ is the zero map, then $T$ is open because $T(X) =\{0\}$, so the image of an open (indeed, every) set in $X$ is $\{0\}$, which is open in topological space $\{0\}$.

Comment: @user0 That only works if $Y$ is a zero dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 1):

If $T$ is surjective, then you can proceed as follows (there is maybe an easier or shorter way):

Let $B_X$ be the open ball of radius $1$ and center $0$ in $X$. More generally, if $M$ is a subspace of $X$, let $B_M$ be the relatively open ball of radius $1$ and center $0$ in $M$. That is, $B_M = B_X\cap M$. By scaling and translation we only have to prove that $T(B_X)$ is open in $Y$. Let $N$ be the kernel of $T$. Now, for any subspace $M$ such that $X = N\oplus M$ we have that $T|M : M\to Y$ is bijective. Hence, by continuity of the inverse, $T(B_M) = (T|M)(B_M)$ is open in $Y$. Let
$$
\mathcal M := \{M : M\subset X\text{ subspace},\;X = N\oplus M\}.
$$
Then we have
$$
B_X = B_N\cup\bigcup_{M\in\mathcal M}B_M.
$$
Hence,
$$
T(B_X) = T(B_N)\cup\bigcup_{M\in\mathcal M}T(B_M).
$$
Now, $T(B_N) = \{0\}$ and each $T(B_M)$ is open, containing zero. Therefore, $T(B_X)$ is open.

Comment: Thank you for the detail solution. But could I apply the open mapping theory to T(X) instead of Y?

Comment: If you have to show that $T : X\to T(X)$ is open, you can either use my proof with $Y$ repaced by $T(X)$ or the open mapping theorem (which in the present case, as was already said in the comments above, would be somewhat of an overkill).

Comment: The question actually uses the following definition of an open map: A mapping $T:X\to Y$ from the topological space $X$ to the topological space $Y$ is said to be _open_ provided the image of each open set in $X$ is open in the topological space $T(X)$, where $T(X)$ has the subspace topology inherited from $Y$.  Would you please post another answer without assuming that $T$ is surjective.